# How to cut slices from a very large image faster using C#?

Tags: c#, image, slice

I have images that could be as big as 20000x20000 pixels in height and width. (Not more than 50 MB). Loading such images into a picture box using C# is very slow and when I need to slice this thing into 200x200 pixels images, it is very slow (few images per second). My current application works fine but very slow and am looking into much faster approaches if available.
This is how I currently loading the image into the image box. (Which is slow too - few seconds to load)

```
resizedImage = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(OriginalImage, new System.Drawing.Size((int)(OriginalImage.Width * zoomFactor), (int)(OriginalImage.Height * zoomFactor)));
            imgBox.Image = resizedImage;
```

What is the best way to slice this image faster?

This is my current slicing routine .

```
private void CropSolderJoints()
        {
            //ordinatesToCrop CordsToCrop = createCordinatesToCrop();
            try
            {
                PB.Maximum = Adjustedcordinates.Pins.Count;

                double OriginX = Convert.ToDouble(txtOriginX.Text);
                double OriginY = Convert.ToDouble(txtOriginY.Text);
                double Scale = Convert.ToDouble(txtScale.Text);
                double BumpSize = Convert.ToDouble(txtBumpSize.Text);

                Stopwatch watch = new Stopwatch();
                watch.Start(); 

                System.Drawing.PointF pos = new System.Drawing.PointF();

                double zoomFactor = (float)(double)(Math.Max(imgBox.Width, imgBox.Height) / (double)Math.Max(OriginalImage.Width, OriginalImage.Height));
                System.Drawing.Size lensPixelSize = new System.Drawing.Size((int)Math.Round(BumpSize / zoomFactor), (int)Math.Round(BumpSize / zoomFactor));
                Rectangle CropJointRectangle = new Rectangle(0, 0, (int)Math.Round(BumpSize / zoomFactor), (int)Math.Round(BumpSize / zoomFactor));

                int pinCount = 0;
                float radius = (float)(BumpSize) / 2;
                foreach (PinCordinates p in Adjustedcordinates.Pins)
                {
                    {
                        {
                            PB.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate {

                            }));

                            string folderName = new DirectoryInfo(imageFolder).Name;
                            string filename = dgvImages.SelectedCells[1].Value.ToString();
                            string Imagefilename = String.Format("{0}_{1}_{2}_{3}", folderName, Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(filename), p.defect.ToString(), p.PinLabel);
                            string saveFilePath = String.Format("{0}\\{1}.{2}", imageFolder, Imagefilename, "png");

                            float TopLeftX = (float)(OriginX + (float)(p.Cordinates.X * Scale));
                            float TopLeftY = (float)(OriginY + (float)(p.Cordinates.Y * Scale));
                            float length = (float)(BumpSize);
                            float width = (float)(BumpSize);

                            pos = new System.Drawing.PointF((float)(TopLeftX), (float)(TopLeftY));

                            imageLens.Location = pkg.GetLensPosition(pos, imageLens);
                            imageLens.Size = lensUseRelativeSize
                                           ? pkg.GetScaledLensSize(imgBox.ClientRectangle, SourceImage.Size, lensPixelSize)
                                           : lensPixelSize;

                            RectangleF section = pkg.CanvasToImageRect(imgBox.ClientRectangle, SourceImage.Size, imageLens);
                            Bitmap imgJoint = new Bitmap((int)Math.Round(BumpSize / zoomFactor), (int)Math.Round(BumpSize / zoomFactor));
                            Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(imgJoint);
                            pkg.DrawImageSelection(g, CropJointRectangle, section, SourceImage);

                            g.DrawImage(imgJoint, 0, 0);
                            picZoom.Image = imgJoint;
                            imgJoint.Save(saveFilePath);
                            PB.Value = pinCount;
                            pinCount++;
                            picZoom.Refresh();
                        }
                    }
                }
                PB.Value = 0;
                watch.Stop();
                label1.Text = watch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds.ToString();
                MessageBox.Show("Slicing completed sucessfully." + pinCount.ToString() + "bumps sliced.");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Are you loading the original image every iteration that you do the slice? I also see that you are using a lot of disposable objects without ever disposing them, this can be detrimental for GDI objects.

Comment: I am loading my image only once.I could dispose them or reuse inside the loop until all slices are done.

Comment: @RonBeyer a good point but it will generally only protect from GDI faults not to _make things faster_

Comment: What is the empty `.Invoke` for, and the extra scope inside the `foreach` loop? Try suspending the layout on the form (`.SuspendLayout()`) before slicing and then resume it (`.ResumeLayout()`) after and see if that speeds anything up. BTW, having 10x10 (100) 200x200 pixel images will take as much or more memory than a single 20000x20000 pixel image, so I'm not sure you are gaining anything by slicing it up.